# Cleanest way to horizontally centre table cell in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `<li>` element with its display property set to `table-cell` inside a relatively positioned div.

It needs to be a table cell as I want to use the `vertical-align: middle` property. The issue right now is centring the cell itself, not its contents.

[image: desired effect]

Here's the source:

```
<ul>
<div id="outer">
<li>Hello</li>
</div>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { padding-left: 0;}
#outer {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: centre; /* this centred the text in the cell rather than the cell*/
}
#outer li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* absolutely no effect, same for 'margin: auto' */
}
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coz24phx/).

The only way I could get it to work was by shrinking the div 'outer' by an amount that is compensated with `padding-left` to manually shift the cell to the centre, but that feels like a violation of all decorum. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: aside -- that is invalid html an ul can have just li tags as direct childrens

Comment: I'm aware. The issue is that when I displayed the li tags as table cells, they were no longer block-level (obvious reasons), which I need as I'm stacking a number of these on top of each other, rather than side-by-side. Any suggestion?

Comment: The text will be long long ? if just one line use lin-height to center vertical .... or if you can use flexbox or if you finally want table-cell you will need an extra-element. https://jsfiddle.net/coz24phx/2/

Comment: if you're still using an extra `<div>` to wrap the `<li>` then why don't you use it in proper way inside your `<li>` killing 2 birds with 1 stone - making the HTML valid and solving your issue?

Comment: *`center` (might explain any failure for this to work)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `table-cell` to vertically align text in a `li`. What you actually need to do is set the `height` and `line-height` to the same thing. Then you can display with `inline-block` to achive the centering.

```
#outer li {
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Additionally you shouldn't use a `div` element inside a `ul` block. Put the ID on the `ul` if you need to.

```
<ul id="outer">
    <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have your div inside the li and not the other way around

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="inner">
      Hello
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;

}

li .inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coz24phx/1/)

**EDIT:** If you want vertical centering, you should include a child div in your table-cell. The table-cell will ignore the set width and will collapse based on the width of the table, so have your text in a block level element inside it instead

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="inner-text">
      Hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display:table;
}

li .inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

li .inner-text {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coz24phx/6/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the cell is wrapped inside an anonymous block-level table.

That table is not centered relatively to the `div` because block-level boxes ignore parent's `text-align`.

It would work if the table was inline-level. Styling it with `display: inline-table` would be enough, but the problem is that you can't select anonymous elements.

The anonymous table would be inline-level if the div had `display: inline`, but that would break your layout.

What you should do is get rid of tables and use flexbox:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul > li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
li{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
#outer li {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 150px;
   line-height: 30px;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with `padding-left` also the unnecessary div.

```
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}

#outer li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table-cell;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coz24phx/3/)

Comment: Why the down vote? It achieves what you asked for. If you want to keep the div, use it correctly like others have suggested.

Answer (score -3):

`display:inline-block` on the li

Comment: That defeats the purpose of having it display as a table cell. I need `vertical-align: middle`.

Comment: Don't need the vertical align in your mock up

Comment: The vertical align affects the text. That's "Cell Content" in the image above and "Hello" in the jsfiddle. It puts the text in the (vertical) centre of the cell.